# SharePoint OOTB Workflow Problem

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I'm getting this error message when trying to add an approval workflow.

> There has been an error while loading
>   the form. A required resource could
>   not be downloaded. To try to resume
>   the download, refresh the page.

Any ideas why?

(Googling didn't find any solutions, was wondering what this community had in mind)

Answer (score 1):

Do you get to the "_layouts/AddWrkfl.aspx" page? If yes, do you get to "_layouts/WrkSetng.aspx"?

If you are not able to get to AddWrkfl.aspx, I would start by disabling any custom workflows (features) and try again. The idea here is when SharePoint loads up the page it collects a list of Workflow Templates deployed to display it on page.

Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: I got it.. turns out it was another httpmodule interferring some stuff (dont ask:P) works now.